# How to change delimiter in C# datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I converted excel table to datatable, but probably because of regional settings of makers of document, delimiter is dot, and when I send datatable to SQL server DB table, it doesn't recognize dot as delimiter and if I have value of 100 in SQL table it is 10000, and so on.

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier if you shared your code. Have you tried setting the decimal separator in the CultureInfo of your thread?

```
string sCurrentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(sCurrentCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```